# AngularJS: Injecting a searchBar view into main view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application

I am trying to add some functionality to inject a searchBar into the main view upon clicking the url tag. First I will post the "index.html" file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppController">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>A checklist</h1>
      <div>
      <a href="#search" >Search</a>
      </div>
       <div ng-view></div>
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" ng-hide="items &amp;&amp; items.length > 0">
        There are no items yet.
      </div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addItem(newItem)">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <div class="checkbox col-xs-9">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="updateItem(item)"/> {{item.description}}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button class="pull-right btn btn-danger" type="button" title="Delete"
              ng-click="deleteItem(item)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newItem" placeholder="Enter the description..." />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-disabled="!newItem" title="Add">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>  
   <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./controllers/AppController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./controllers/SearchController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./services/ItemFactory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./routing/route.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have the "routing.js" file next:

```
        angular.module("myApp").config(function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider  
          .when('/search', {
              templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
              controller: 'SearchController'
          })

          .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
          });
     });
```

Here is the "search.html" view:

```
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
<div>{{ searchText }}</div>
</div>
```

Here is the SearchController:

```
angular.module('controllerModule').controller('SearchController',function($scope){
$scope.searchText = "I can haz cheezeburger";
    });
```

So, in theory, I can inject the search Text page into "index.html" page.

So here are my questions:

1. For some reason my code does not work; perhaps some syntax errors with the code I have posted or some of the other pieces of the program that I can not find.  Can anyone tell me what might be the problem?  I can post the rest of the project if anyone requests.
2. Ideally, I want to eventually inject a search bar instead of a string; could anyone give me some feedback on how I could do that

Here are other components to project:

"ItemFactory.js"

```
    angular.module("serviceModule").factory("Item", ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/items/:id', {
        id: '@id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: "PUT"
        },
        remove: {
          method: "DELETE"
        }
      });
    }]);
```

Here is "app.js".

```
angular.module("controllerModule", []);
angular.module("serviceModule", []);
angular.module("myApp", ["ngResource", "ngRoute", "controllerModule", "serviceModule"]);
```

Here is "AppController.js".  I have posted this on another question thread of mine.

```
    angular.module("controllerModule").controller("AppController", ['$scope', 'Item', function($scope, Item){
    Item.query(function(response) {
        $scope.items = response ? response : [];
    });

    $scope.addItem = function(description) {
        new Item({
            description: description,
            checked: false
        }).$save(function(item) {
            $scope.items.push(item);
        });
        $scope.newItem = "";
    };

    $scope.updateItem = function(item) {
        item.$update();
    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
        item.$remove(function() {
            $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
        });
    };
}]);
```